# ZF2 - Missing argument 1 for XXXController::__construct()

Tags: php, controller, zend-framework2, factory

I am trying to use a factory to create a controller instance:

```
class AuthenticationController extends AbstractActionController
    implements ControllerProviderInterface 
{
    private $loginLogoutService;

    public function __construct($lls)
    {
        $this->loginLogoutService = $lls;
    }

    public function getControllerConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Main\Controller\Authentication' => function(ControllerManager $cm) {
                    $sm   = $cm->getServiceLocator();
                    $depA = $sm->get('LoginLogoutService');
                    $controller = new AuthenticationController($depA);
                    return $controller;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
```

But I am getting an error message:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for
>   Main\Controller\AuthenticationController::__construct()

Why isn't the factory used to create the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getControllerConfig()` should be in your `Module.php`, not in the controller itself. Everything else looks okay.

Comment: That worked, but why does it have to be in Module.php when doc says ControllerProviderInterface can be used? I just don't get it...

Comment: `ControllerProviderInterface` can only be implemented by `Module.php`. It doesn't make sense for a controller to have an instance method that defines how to create an instance of itself, since the controller manager would have to first create an instance of it to call that method.